# Contact Form - Uncaught Error: Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found

Tags: php

I am receiving the following PHP error 'Uncaught Error: Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found' and I am at a total loss as to why.  The file path is 100% correct and I can see no direct reason as to why the code is not working.

I know PHP is a bit of a minefield so if there are any PHP experts out there who can help with this that would be awesome!

```
require_once("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@test.com"); 
$subject = "Email from Website";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@test.com");
$message = <<<EMAILBODY
    Name: {$_POST['name']}
    Email: {$_POST['email']}
    subject: {$_POST['subject']}
    phone: {$_POST['phone']}
    company: {$_POST['company']}
    Message: {$_POST['message']}
    EMAILBODY;
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $message);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY';  // Your API key
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
if($response->statusCode() == 202){
    echo "Email sent successfully";
}else{
    echo "Email could not be sent";
}
```

Comment: Your code does not look like anything from their php api examples, nor for the V2 version nor for the V3 version of their api...

Comment: I have to be honest and say that I actually used a code snippet as I have been hitting my head against a brick wall with this and this seemed to be a good solution.   PHP definitely isn't my strong point so would be grateful of any advice of how to implement this correctly

Comment: You should start with their documentation for the api version you are using: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/

Answer (score -2):

Make slide modify in this initial line

require_once("sendgrid/sendgrid.php");
i.e remove '-php' from directory and filename.